# Validar chave api do google

Tags: php, javascript, regex, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou fazendo um aplicação, onde terei que validar uma chave API do google maps. O problema é que não sei quais padrões ela segue:

```
AIzaSyA-OlPHUh2W7LUZXVjQjjxQ8fdCWdAASmc
```

Aqui é visível que são letras maiúsculas e minusculas, números e traços. Mas será que sempre será assim?

Alguém conhece o padrão dessas chaves, e como fazer isso com JS e PHP?

***JS:***

```
var inputstr="A3aa622-_";
var regex=/^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{30,50}$/g;
if (regex.test(inputstr)){
    alert("sim");
}else{
    alert("Nao");
}
```

Comment: Acho que a única forma de valida-los seria efetuando um GET/POST para a API usando tal chave. Dessa forma a API deve retornar se a chave é verdeira ou não.

Comment: Entendo. No momento não me importa muito se a api é verdadeira ou falsa, eu gostaria mais validar, para que a apessoa não adicione qualquer coisa, algo assim, será que ajudaria: `regex=/^[A-Za-z0-9-_]{30,50}$/g;`

Answer (score 1):

**Assumindo que** a chave possua *exatamente* `39` caracteres de tamanho; Seja formada por caracteres alfanuméricos (letras e números), em qualquer caso (maiúsculos ou minúsculos); E pode apresentar traços `-` e underlines `_`.

Seguem os códigos em `JS` e `PHP` capazes de fazer essa pré-validação*:

Código em `JavaScript`:

```
function is_valid_key( key )
{
    if( key.length != 39 ) return false;
    var regx = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+$");
    return regx.test(key);
}
```

Código em `PHP`:

```
function is_valid_key( $key )
{
    if( strlen( $key ) != 39 ) return false;
    return preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/', $key );
}
```

- O usuário @Inkeliz está certo, a única maneira de validar a chave é por meio de um GET/POST na API do Google, por isso, o código acima é apenas uma pré-validação a fim de se evitar um `overhead` desnecessário de GETs e POSTs na rede.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Detalhe, pelos testes que realizei, aceita _ (underline) ...  ATT

Comment: @abcd: ajustado!

Comment: @Locobus Lembrando que não é possível saber se realmente se manterá estes valores para as chaves, pois em nenhum local encontrei informações sobre a quantidade de caracteres e quais caracteres podem ser usados... ATT